# Dynamic CSS Style (CSS sld) to pass environment and property name variable

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

we are trying to make css style using geoserver's CSS extension,
I have weather data in my table, like **temp_max, temp_min, and rainfall** which divided into classes depending on their range values, now we want to pass **'class_n'** variable dynamically which is working fine, but we quite stuck on How to pass *attribute names* dynamically (temp_max, temp_min,...)  ?

Also there is catch if propname is passed for rainfall then all color codes should be in reverse order! (if it so)

```
/* @title class 1 */
[ FEATURECLA = 'temp_max_deg_c' ] >= env('class1',-1)] <= env('class2',-1) {
    fill: #bdffe9;
}
```

Here we can see I'm try to pass both attribute name which can be 'temp_max_deg_c' or 'temp_min_deg_c' depending upon user response, but its not working as expected

```
/* @title class 2 */
[env('propname','temp_max_deg_c') > env('class2',-1)] [temp_max_deg_c <= env('class3',-1)] {
    fill: #ffff06;
}
```

If we pass without dynamically it is working fine for class value

```
/* @title class 3 */
[temp_max_deg_c > env('class3',-1)] [temp_max_deg_c <= env('class4',-1)] {
    fill: #fcd47b;
}
/* @title class 4 */
[temp_max_deg_c > env('class4',-1)] {
    fill: #fb5604;
}
/* @title taluka */
* {
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    label: [thnname];
    label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
}
```

Same thing is written is xml sld which is working
where `PropertyName` and `Literal` are dynamically passed into url

```
<Rule>
          <Name>Rainfall1</Name>
          <Name>Dynamic</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall_mm</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>rain1</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#c7e2f4</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
```

Edits as suggested
by passing
`&viewparams=forecast_date:2023-03-02&env=forecast_for:temp_max_class`
now we managed to break our style like this after adjusting variables into the layer, **temp_max, temp_min, and rainfall** as specified before we are trying to style layer according to user input which can be one of the above variable, the below code work for only one attribute if specied into the css style

```
/* @title taluka */
* {
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    label: [thnname];
    label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
}

/* @title class recode */
* {
  fill: [    
    recode(temp_min_class,
        1,'#bdffe9', 2,'#ffff06',
        3,'#fcd47b', 4,'#fb5604')
        ];
}
```

but non of the methods work for *env* substitution,

1. **Using 'env'**

```
/* @title class recode */
* {
  fill: [    
    recode(env('forecast_for', 'temp_max_class'),
        1,'#bdffe9', 2,'#ffff06',
        3,'#fcd47b', 4,'#fb5604')
        ];
}
```

this renders only primary layer (Taluka) and shows blank in color code.

2. **Using 'FEATURECLA'**

```
/* @title class recode */
* {
  fill: [    
    recode([ FEATURECLA = env('forecast_for', 'temp_max_class') ],
        1,'#bdffe9', 2,'#ffff06',
        3,'#fcd47b', 4,'#fb5604')
        ];
}
```

which showing error

```
Error at line 13. Encountered "<EOF>" at line 2, column 15. Was expecting one of: <STRING_LITERAL> ... "true" ... "false" ... "point" ... "linestring" ... "polygon" ... "multipoint" ... "multilinestring" ... "multipolygon" ... "geometrycollection" ... "envelope" ... "srid" ... "(" ... ")" ... "[" ... "-" ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <FLOATING_LITERAL> ... <DATE> ... <DATE_TIME> ... <IDENTIFIER> ... Parsing : recode(.
```

Please help with error

[image: without env variable]

[image: With env variable, renders primary layer only, without color coded areas]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: edited question as suggested

Comment: I still don't see where you show what you have tried for the attributes?

Comment: 'temp_max_deg_c ' is attribute present in table, and others like 'temp_min_deg_c', we can find that I'm trying to pass it dynamically,  like we do in XML sld, using env variable

Comment: OK, so what's not working for you?#

Comment: please refer edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a filter function called "property" that can resolve a property based on the name it has been provided.

So something like this may work:

`[ FEATURECLA = env('X', 'temp_min_deg_c) ] >= property(env('attname', 'class1')]`

and then you provide the desired property name in the GetMap URL, adding `&env=X:temp_max_deg_c;attname:class2`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Andrea Aime,  we are trying to pass both `[ FEATURECLA] = 'X' ` & `class1` dynamically, where X and class1 should be passed from url. `X` can be `'temp_max_deg_c'` or `'temp_min_deg_c'`

Comment: Example updated...

Comment: Please refer updated question